# Laravel 4 Resource Routing

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I would like to know how to put constrains on resource routes $id. For example I would like to  get

```
user/{id}
```

to make sure that id in just a number and nothing else.
I've registered my resources with

```
Route::resource('user','UserController');
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Why though? You should by validating the value anyway so if it's not a number it's not going to work.

Comment: Well I know if I did something like this Router::get('user/{id}', array('as' => 'user', 'uses' => 'UserController@show'))->where('id', '[0-9]+'); works. But I need it for resource routes and don't know what to do.

Comment: Yeah Laravel generates the different routes (`get`, `put`, `post`) for resources automatically for you which means you can't actually adjust the route by setting requirements such as ensuring the ID is only a number. Like I said, it shouldn't really matter as if the user tries to put in say `user/foo` you should be doing database checks that will say, "hey 'foo' doesn't exist in the database, that's a faulty record", and then redirecting or showing an error.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll do that instead. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

You could use route parameters as explain [in the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters). The (quite verbose) solution will be :

```
Route::get('user',           array('uses' => 'UserController@index'));
Route::get('user/create',    array('uses' => 'UserController@create'));
Route::post('user',          array('uses' => 'UserController@store'));
Route::get('user/{id}',      array('uses' => 'UserController@show'))->where('id', '[0-9]+');
Route::get('user/{id}/edit', array('uses' => 'UserController@edit'))->where('id', '[0-9]+');
Route::put('user/{id}',      array('uses' => 'UserController@update'))->where('id', '[0-9]+');
Route::delete('user/{id}',   array('uses' => 'UserController@destroy'))->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Unfortunately, this will thrown a 500 (NotFoundHttpException) and not a 404, but it could protect you against security or database inconsistency issues.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay. I just saw your question.

If you use Laravel 4.1 you can use the Route::resource method as follow:

```
Route::resource('user', 'UserController', array('only' => array('create', 'store', 'update', 'destroy')));
```

Then you can then add another action using the Route::get() method as follow:

```
Route::get('customaction/{id}', 'UserController@customAction')
```

You can set the the required parameters to this custom route.